# I dont see a choise of "Open with Live Server" from the context menu in VS Code program

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed 'live server' in VS Code program (with internet explanation), but I dont see a choice of "Open with Live Server" from the context menu.

(I try to running a html code file).

Please help me to understand what is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating an HTML file, right-click on any place where the HTML code is. From the menu that appears, you will see open with live sever. Click on it. You are good to go.